# Bootstrap carousel not working with angular6

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, carousel, angular6

Iam using a bootstrap4 carousel with angular6, but getting below errors. Since iam using bootstrap, I had to use jQuery as well. I have installed bootsrap, jquery modules via npm. I checked many treads in stackoverflow but not helping. The error in console is `AppComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__(...).carousel is not a function`

```
ERROR in src/app/header/header.component.ts(17,20): error TS2339: Property 'carousel' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

MyComponent.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-header',
   templateUrl: './header.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('.carousel').carousel();
  }
}
```

Below is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="bd-example">
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=777&amp;fg=555&amp;text=First slide" alt="First slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1649235df3c%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23555%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1649235df3c%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22285.921875%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EFirst%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=666&amp;fg=444&amp;text=Second slide" alt="Second slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1649235df42%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1649235df42%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22247.3203125%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3ESecond%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" data-src="holder.js/800x400?auto=yes&amp;bg=555&amp;fg=333&amp;text=Third slide" alt="Third slide [800x400]" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_1649235df44%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_1649235df44%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22277%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" data-holder-rendered="true">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
              "scripts": [
                "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
              ]
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor: ditch jquery, and use ng-bootstrap. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this, it does not have animations. So I was trying for jquery bootstrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should import Bootstrap in your component too:

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

Comment: Thank you. I Tried but Iam getting below error:

Failed to compile

./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in 'c:\uiTestApp\ui-test-app\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'

Comment: yes that's because some of our modules need Popper.js (Tooltip/Popovers/Dropdown) so you need to install Popper.js and include it too with: import 'popper.js'; before Bootstrap import